# Sort COALESCE generated columns in a dynamic pivot table

Tags: sql-server, pivot, coalesce

I would like to sort the columns, but I get the following error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

The years select query returns them in order, but they are shuffled when handled by the `COALESCE` function.

**How can I prevent this? Or even better, control the sorting?**

**NOTE:** The sorting works if I put a `TOP 10` in the subquery. Super weird...

```sql
-- variables
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @pivot_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique
DECLARE @select_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique

-- columns
SELECT -- top 10 makes the sorting work
    -- [2018], [2020], [2017], [2019] -- not ordered
    @pivot_list = COALESCE(@pivot_list + ', ', '') + '[' + PIVOT_COLUMN + ']',
    @select_list = COALESCE(@select_list + ', ', '') + 'ISNULL([' + PIVOT_COLUMN + '], 0) as [' + PIVOT_COLUMN + ']'
FROM (
    SELECT
        -- 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020 -- ordered
        cast(year(addate) as nvarchar(4)) as PIVOT_COLUMN
    FROM tHE_Move M
    where addate >= '01.01.2017'
    group by year(addate)
    --  order by year(addate) asc -- <-------------------------------------- doesn't work
) as PIVOT_COLUMNS

-- query
SET @sql = '
; WITH PivotData AS (
    select
        shop,
        y AS PIVOT_COLUMN,
        sum(revenueNoVAT) revenueNoVAT
    from (
        SELECT
            SS.acName2 shop,
            year(m.addate) y,
            MI.anPVVATBase revenueNoVAT
        FROM tHE_MoveItem MI
            JOIN tHE_Move M ON MI.acKey = M.acKey
            JOIN tHE_SetSubj SS ON M.acIssuer = SS.acSubject
        WHERE m.acDocType in (
            ' + '''3210''' + ',
            ' + '''3220''' + ',
            ' + '''3230''' + ',
            ' + '''3240''' + '
        )
    ) t1
    group by
        shop,
        y
)
SELECT shop, ' + @select_list + '
FROM PivotData
    PIVOT (
        sum(revenueNoVAT)
        FOR PIVOT_COLUMN
        IN (' + @pivot_list + ')
    ) piv
order by shop desc
'

-- execution
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Have you tried the `UNLESS` part? Try `Select Top 100 Percent` and see what you get.

Comment: As the error tells you, you can't put an `ORDER BY` in a subquery; put it outside of it.

Comment: Interesting. I added `top 10` and it works. Adding `top(100) percent` doesn't. What is the `UNLESS` part, can't find anything?

Comment: @Larnu I need to sort it before it becomes a string. If I put it outside the query, it has nothing to sort. Also, they are sorted in the subquery. They get shuffled in the string generation process.

Comment: Which is why the `ORDER BY` goes in the outer query, where the assignment brakes place. Personally, however ,I'd  suggest `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH` over a self referencing variable.

Comment: Example of `ORDER BY` working as expected: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8341e88f2c365a9febfa45d7d6fdbc36)